# Jmeter oracle connection issue

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0, jmeter-4.0, jmeter-3.2

While connecting to oracle database from jmeter, i was receiving a connection error.

Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-01882: timezone region not found
)

And now I want to set the following parameter in Jmeter. Is there a way?

oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false

Comment: add to question jdbc jar you are using, oracle version and your JDBC configuration settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to system.properties located in jmeter/bin folder:

> oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion=false